# getting fatal error while creating model config with database in Alanstormdotcom_Weblog

Tags: magento-1.9, database, fatal-error, localhost

I want to link the model with the database in magento and get the data from the database but i can not figured it out. Is anybody help me to solve this problem. I spend long time to find its problem but i am fail. so i am here to find its solution, is there any Magento Geek who can help me to solve this problem? Its been very grateful if you can solve this problem.

I got following error when i run the below link:
http://localhost/magentonew/weblog/index/testModel/id/1

> ```
> Loading the blogpost with an ID of 1
> Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\magentonew\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php
> ```
>
> on line 225

This is my code:
..\Alanstormdotcom\Weblog\etc\config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Alanstormdotcom_Weblog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Alanstormdotcom_Weblog>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
    <routers>
        <weblog>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Alanstormdotcom_Weblog</module>
                <frontName>weblog</frontName>
            </args>
        </weblog>
    </routers>
</frontend>    

    <global>
    <!-- ... -->
    <models>
        <weblog>
            <class>Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_Model</class>
            <!--
            need to create our own resource, can't just
            use core_mysql4
            -->
            <resourceModel>weblog_mysql4</resourceModel>
             <weblog_mysql4>
            <class>Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_Model_Mysql4</class>
        </weblog_mysql4>

        </weblog>
    </models>
       <!-- ... -->
    <resources>
        <weblog_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </weblog_write>
        <weblog_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </weblog_read>
    </resources>
    <!-- ... -->
    </global>
</config>
```

Contoller file:..\Alanstormdotcom\Weblog\controllers\IndexController.php

```
<?php

class Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
  public function testModelAction() {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $blogpost = Mage::getModel('weblog\blogpost');
    echo("Loading the blogpost with an ID of ".$params['id']);
    $blogpost->load($params['id']);
    $data = $blogpost->getData();
    var_dump($data);
    }
}
```

Blogspot.php: ..\Alanstormdotcom\Weblog\Model\Blogspot.php

```
<?php 

class Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_Model_Blogpost extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract

{

    protected function _construct()

    {

        $this->_init('weblog/blogpost');

    }

}
```

:..\Alanstormdotcom\Weblog\Model\Mysql4\Blogspot.php

```
<?php 


class Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_Model_Mysql4_Blogpost extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract

{

    protected function _construct()

    {

        $this->_init('alanstormdotcom_weblog/blogpost', 'blogpost_id');

    }   

}
```

and i also create table in my database using following query:

> ```
> >     CREATE TABLE `blog_posts` (
> >       `blogpost_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
> >       `title` text,
> >       `post` text,
> >       `date` datetime default NULL,
> >       `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
> >       PRIMARY KEY  (`blogpost_id`)
> >     )
> > INSERT INTO `blog_posts` VALUES (1,'My New Title','This is a blog
> > post','2009-07-01 00:00:00','2009-07-02 23:12:30');
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing the resource model entity node, which associates your resource model to your custom table.

```
<models>
    <weblog>
        <class>Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>weblog_mysql4</resourceModel>
        <weblog_mysql4>
            <class>Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <blogpost>blog_posts</blogpost>
            </entities>
        </weblog_mysql4>
    </weblog>
</models>
```

Also

```
class Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_Model_Mysql4_Blogpost extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('weblog/blogpost', 'blogpost_id');
    }   
}
```

Comment: I update entities tag in my config.xml....However I got the same error.